# trying to build a card game that gives a hand of 5 cards in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Enter your a number:"

class Card

  attr_accessor :rank, :suit

  def initialize(rank,suit)
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit
  end  


  def output_card
    puts "#{self.rank} of #{self.suit}"
  end

end  


class Deck

  def initialize
    @cards = []  
    @ranks = [:A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, :J, :Q, :K]
    @suits = [:Spades, :Hearts, :Diamonds, :Clubs]    

    @suits.each do |suit|
      @ranks.each do |rank|
        @cards << Card.new(rank, suit)  
      end 
    end   
  end  

  def shuffle 
    @cards.shuffle!
  end  

  def deal
    @cards.shift 
  end


end 


class Hand

    def initialize(deck)
       @hand = []
        5.times do
         @hand << deck.deal
        end
    end

    def display_hand 
      @hand.each do |card|
         @hand.output_card
         end

    end      
end




hand = Hand.new 
hand.display_hand
puts hand
```

I'm trying to build a card game that outputs a hand of 5 cards. But I'm having trouble outputting the 5 cards. I keep getting this error:

```
card_game.rb:46:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from card_game.rb:64:in `new'
    from card_game.rb:64:in `<main>'
```

When I call:

```
hand = Hand.new 
hand.display_hand
puts hand
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is telling you that you need to construct  a Hand wit a Deck. Below two classes try this code instead :

```
deck = Deck.new # create new deck
hand = Hand.new deck # initialize hand with the deck
hand.display_hand
puts hand
```